# Encoding inputs with varying lengths to use in sklearn model

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have the following dataset:

```
 X = [[{'feature1': 'value1', 'feature2': 'value2'},
      {'feature1': 'value3', 'feature2': 'value4'},
      {'feature1': 'value5', 'feature2': 'value6'}],
    
     [{'feature1': 'value6', 'feature2': 'value7'}],
    
     [{'feature1': 'value8', 'feature2': 'value9'},
     {'feature1': 'value10', 'feature2': 'value11'},
     {'feature1': 'value12', 'feature2': 'value14'},
     {'feature1': 'value15', 'feature2': 'value17'}]]
```

where `value1, value2 ....` are categorical variables, and each list(of dict)  constitutes a single input to my model,(so in X above I have basically just three inputs == three inner lists of dicts) what I did so far is I create a list called `all_possible_combinations` where I put all the possible combinations that the concatenation of values for `feature1` and `feature2` can take, then I create for each dict (pair `(feature1, feature2)`) a one hot encoding using this list of combinations then I sum all the one hot encodings and get basically the same input size no mater how many dicts are in each list, this is the code I got so far:

```
def create_one_vector(all_possible_combinations ,dict_input):
        one_hot = np.zeros((1, len(all_possible_combinations)+1))
        
        try:
            one_hot[0, all_possible_combinations\
                    .index(dict_input["feature1"]+dict_input["feature2"])]= 1
        except ValueError:
            one_hot[0, -1] = 1
            
        return one_hot
    
def create_input_vector(all_possible_combinations, input):

    return np.sum([create_one_vector(all_possible_combinations, input) 
                                       for dict_input in input], axis=0)
```

then to use this in sklearn I did the following:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from functools import partial

create_input  = partial(create_input_vector, all_possible_combinations)
transformer = FunctionTransformer(create_input, validate=True)
transformer.transform(X[0])
```

and I got the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
.
.
.
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     84 
     85 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

How do I get something like this to work as an sklearn transform? Or, do you have any alternative that would allow me to input this to sklearn model?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correct, you would need all possible combination of feature 1 and feature 2 across all your list, you can do this first:

```
f1 = np.concatenate([pd.DataFrame(i).feature1.unique() for i in X])
f2 = np.concatenate([pd.DataFrame(i).feature2.unique() for i in X])
nu = np.array(np.meshgrid(f1,f2)).T.reshape(-1, 2)
all_possible_combinations = [' '.join(i) for i in nu]
```

There are many ways to do this, you can provide this category to onehotencoder (see [help page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)) or as below, use `pd.Categorical` to set it as a category with defined levels before onehot:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

def encode_combination(lst):
    df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
    df['combination'] = pd.Categorical(df.feature1 + " " + df.feature2,
                                       categories=all_possible_combinations)
    return(enc.fit_transform(df[['combination']]))
```

There's a total of 64 combinations in your example, and you can see for each list, it returns 64 columns:

```
encode_combination(X[0])

<3x64 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

encode_combination(X[1])

<1x64 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```